# How to process in a script Bash arguments with spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, escaping, quoting

I have a Bash script which (in a simplified form) does this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function ag_search_and_replace {
  ag -l "$1" "${@:3}" | xargs -r perl -i -pe "s/$1/$2/g"
}

locations="$@"

ag_search_and_replace search replace $locations
```

This works as expected when the argument have no spaces, e.g.:

```
my_script foo bar
```

however, when there are spaces, e.g.:

```
my_script foo "ba r"
```

the script fails.

Is there a simple way to process arguments with spaces?

Answer (score 4):

`"$@"` is the way to do it, but you lose the benefits when you unnecessarily assign it to a regular variable.

```
ag_search_and_replace search replace "$@"
```

If you must create a new named variable, use an array.

```
locations=( "$@" )
ag_search_and_replace search replace "${locations[@]}"
```

Comment: The assignment to regular variable is necessary in the context of the full script :-) This is a simplified version; I've put the assignment for consistency with the script.

Comment: Then the full script is broken.

Comment: What do you refer, specifically, with broken (I assume it's something else other than what you corrected by the reply)?

Comment: Because `location="$@"` and `location="$*"` do *exactly* the same thing, and neither one lets you retrieve the original arguments from `location`. If `location='a b c'`, then did you originally have 1) `a b c`, 2) `a b` and `c`, 3) `a` and `b c`, or 4) `a`, `b`, and `c`?